# The usage of "being" and "in which"

Tags: sentence-construction, conjunctions, clauses, complements, run-on-sentences

Here, I am confused about how to make a meaningful sentence.

This is my idea.  I want to say:

> Another example for under-segmentation is shown in Fig 14. *By this effect,* nearby dormers have merged.  Because of that, an edge referring to a dormer is lost.

So, I express my idea more concisely like this:

> Another instance of ***being*** under-segmentation is illustrated in
>   (Fig. 14) ***in which*** the nearby dormers have merged and it causes to
>   lose a graph edge.

So, my questions are:

- Am I correctly using the word *being*?  I am always confused about when to use it.
- Does *in which* refer to the idea *by this effect*?

Comment: `being under-segmentation` would become `being under-segmented`. I haven't heard `by this effect` and neither found anything relevant in Google, so I am assuming it is your personal usage. If I think about the literal meaning of it, `in which` isn't quite meaning the same; I am not claiming `in which` makes the sentence wrong, but it is not being used the same way `By the effect` was used.

Comment: *it causes to lose a graph edge* is ungrammatical: you must either convert to a noun phrase, *it causes **loss of** a graph edge*, or provide the verb *lose* with a subject, *it causes [something] to lose a graph edge*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In “Another instance of being under-segmentation is illustrated...” in your second quote, use of *being* isn't wrong; however, *segmentation* should be  *segmented*, a past participle.

In the balance of the sentence (which, with a grammar fix, is “... in (Fig. 14) in which the nearby dormers have merged and caused loss of a graph edge”),  *in which* primarily refers to Fig. 14, and secondarily to “Another instance”.  I don't see any way to read it as referring to under-segmentation.  Consider a revision like the following.

> Fig. 14, where nearby dormers have merged, is another example of under-segmentation, with consequent loss of a graph edge.

Comment: As you say, *Another instance of being undersegmented* isn't wrong, but the construction with *being* is superfluous: *Another instance of under-segmentation* would be better.